# Dataframe column to list of strings (with groupby)

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, list

I have a dataframe and I want to get one of its columns as a list of strings, so that from something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['a','a','a','b','b'],
         'location':['1','2','3','4','5']})
```

I can get a dataframe like:

```
a  ['1','2','3']
b  ['4','5']
```

where one column is the customer and another is a list of strings of their location.

I have tried df.astype(str).values.tolist() but I can't seem to groupby in order to get the list per customer.

Comment: `df.groupby('customer')['location'].apply(list)`?

Comment: like that but I can't do like this because then I don't have a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
df.groupby('customer').location.unique()
Out[58]: 
customer
a    [1, 2, 3]
b       [4, 5]
Name: location, dtype: object
```

This is `string` type , just did not show the quote

```
df.groupby('customer').location.unique()[0][0]
Out[61]: '1'
```

Also you should know string input in list dose not show quote in pandas' object

```
pd.Series([['1','2']])
Out[64]: 
0    [1, 2]
dtype: object
```